# Meaning of "electrostatic" and "nonresonant laser" fields

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, condensed-matter, laser, molecules

I just read the following sentence:

> *The molecule is subjected to an electrostatic field $E$ combined with a nonresonant laser field of intensity $I$, whose linear polarization is collinear with $E$.*

Does this mean that there are two different fields, one static field and one induced by a laser? What does nonresonant mean in this case?

The phrase is taken from the second sentence in the second paragraph of [this paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/1367-2630/13/6/063036/pdf/1367-2630_13_6_063036.pdf).

Comment: Can you provide details on the source of the sentence? For example, author & title or a link?

Comment: It is taken from the second sentence in the second paragraph of the following paper http://iopscience.iop.org/1367-2630/13/6/063036/pdf/1367-2630_13_6_063036.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that there are two different fields, one static field and one induced by a laser?

Yes, that is exactly right.
There is a static (meaning not time dependent) electric field $\vec{E}_\text{static}$ $(*)$ and there is also a time-varying electric field $\vec{E}_\text{laser}$ from the laser.
Since we are told the laser field is linearly polarized in the same direction as the static field, we can write the total electric field amplitude at the molecule as

$$E(t) = E_\text{static} + E_\text{laser}(t) $$

where dropping the vector symbols means that we're talking only about amplitude.

> What does nonresonant means in this case?

Molecules have internal resonances.
An internal resonance is roughly an available vibration frequency.
Think of a tuning fork: if you whack it, it vibrates at a particular frequency $f$.
The tuning fork has a *resonance* at frequency $f$.
Molecules do this too.
Saying that the laser is nonresonant means that the frequency of the laser radiation is not near any of the molecule's resonances.

$(*)$: What I call $\vec{E}_\text{static}$ you called $E$. I add the subscript "static" to remind us that this is the part which is not varying in time.

Comment: interesting, I think I understood the nonresonant part. But in their paper the laser field does not(!) depend on time. Does this make sense to you? Moreover, in their equation, only the laser field couples to the polarizability and only the static field couples to the dipole moment. Do you think this is correct?

Comment: @user167575 I think you're confused by of a confusing convention. When people say the laser field is not time dependent they mean the *amplitude* is not time dependent. The actual electric and magnetic fields are always time dependent. As for the second question you ask in your comment, that would make a good question to post separately :-)